# If I declare a template function, Does templates automatically create different versions of a function at runtime??

Tags: c++

I want to know what happens in the memory when I declare a template function ??
and when the actual code for template function is generated ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for templates the most important thing is, that everything happens during compile time. Machine itself must have a code and programs do not generate code themselves, but compilers do it.

Therefore you do not have to worry about RAM itself, but it does not mean, that there are no problems with them.

The most common problem with templates is so called code bloating. Generally this happens, when some of the functions are generated during instantiation, although they are not dependant on template type. Let's see following example:

```
template <typename T>
class templatedClass{
public:
std::type_info getTypeId();
void printHello()
};

template <typename T>
std::type_info templatedClass<T>::getTypeId(){return typeid(*this);}

template <typename T>
void templatedClass<T>::printHello(){std::cout<<"Hello world!\n";}
```

Now even though `printHello` makes no use of type `T`, it will be generated (probably, maybe compilers started to support this kind of issues) for every type `T`, that was used to instantiate `templatedClass`. This is rather harmless for PCs, although in embedded programming it may play a big role, as memory for the text is limited.

To solve this problem one could do:

```
class printHelloClass{
public:
void printHello();
};

template <typename T>
class templatedClass : public printHelloClass{
public:
std::type_info getTypeId();
};
```

Now, because of the fact, that all instantiations of templated class inherit from one class, that has printHello() method only one function printHello() will exist in memory for code.

I think it is the only memory issue with templates. You do not have to worry about RAM etc. only about code size itself.

Answer (score 2):

A code for template function is generated when the function is instantiated. The functions are often instantiated when they are first time called (in the code), but there are other ways to instantiate a function - do a so-called 'explicit instantiation'.

As for the memory, nothing happens to it. Since instnatiation happens during compile time, by the time program is run all the functions are already instnatiated and the code is generated.